# Display the name and max age

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display the record with the highest value in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767996/how-to-display-the-record-with-the-highest-value-in-oracle)

I am supposed to display the name and age of the oldest person from the database. The code I used displays the name and the calculated age of several people, but it won't display the single oldest person. How do I get this to work?
here is my code

```
select dr_drvname as "Name", trunc(max((sysdate-dr_brthdate)/365)) as "Highest AGE"
from driver,dual
group by dr_drvname;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way in Oracle would be something like:

```
SELECT
    dr_drvname AS "Name",
    trunc(months_between(sysdate, dr_birthdate) / 12) AS "Highest Age"
FROM
(
SELECT
    dr_drvname,
    dr_birthdate
FROM
    driver
ORDER BY
    dr_birthdate
)
WHERE
    ROWNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT top 1
  Firstname, LastName, Max([BirthDate]) as Oldest    
  FROM [Employees]
  group by BirthDate, FirstName, LastName
```

Note:  What are the requirements if multiple people have the same birth date?

Comment: I could use WHERE trunc((sysdate-dr_brthdate)/365) >97 because I know the highest age is 98, but that wouldn't hold true all the time. There's no requirements listed.

Comment: I tested my original suggestion and it failed miserably so I edited my answer.  You still have to put the part in to calculate the age.

Comment: The question is tagged for Oracle and Oracle doesn't support the `top 1` syntax (though there are some enhancements coming in 12g that can be used instead).

Comment: I didn't know Oracle didn't support top 1.  I think you can use WHERE rownum = 1  (I don't have Oracle on my home machine believe it or not).

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytic functions

```
select dr_drvname as "Name", 
       trunc( months_between( sysdate, dr_birthdate )/ 12 ) "Highest Age"
  from (select dr_drvname ,
               dr_birthdate,
               rank() over (order by dr_birthdate) rnk
          from driver)
 where rnk = 1;
```